# объединение 2х таблиц MySQL и вывод данных в таблицу

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Всем привет,  такой вопрос: 
есть две таблицы `users`(id, username, FIO, uchebnaya_group) и `rubezhnii_kontrol`(это то,где преподаватели ставят оценки обучающимся)(iduser, rk1, rk2, itog, sr_ball)

Необходимо создать запрос, где будут выводиться все пользователи конкретной учебной группы и оценка поставленная преподавателем в таблице `rubezhnii_kontrol`
[image: так выглядит таблица]
Вот сам запрос

```
$query =    "SELECT 
            surname,
            fullname,
            otchestvo
            FROM users
            WHERE nomber=237";
$res = mysqli_query($dbh, $query);
```

работаю в phpmyadmin

как вывести именно те оценки,которые преподаватель поставил конкретному пользователю

вот сама таблица
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

буду очень признательна за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Для получения связных данных разных таблиц Вам может помочь оператор JOIN.
Конкретно для Вашего примера:

```
SELECT users.surname
     , users.fullname
     , users.otchestvo
     , rubezhnii_kontrol.rk1
     , rubezhnii_kontrol.rk2
     , rubezhnii_kontrol.itog
     , rubezhnii_kontrol.sr_ball 
FROM users 
JOIN rubezhnii_kontrol ON users.id = rubezhnii_kontrol.iduser 
WHERE users.nomber = 237
```